# How do you create a UserGroup Group with a Type of sharedSigningGroup in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create a UserGroup Group with a Type of "sharedSigningGroup" in a DocuSign development environment. I can create a UserGroup Group with a Type of "customGroup" but when I try to specify a Type of "sharedSigningGroup" it creates a "customGroup" instead. Here is the JSON structure for the call:

```
    {
        "groups": [
          {
            "groupName": "19-1250 Signing",
            "groupType": "sharedSigningGroup"
          }
        ]
    }
```

I am POSTing the data to the correct URL path, /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/groups and it works for "customGroup" Type.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Signing Group, there's a separate URL you need to hit:

`POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/[[account_id]]/signing_groups`

With a body of something like this:

```
{
"groups": [
    {
        "signingGroupId": "",
        "groupName": "newSigningGroup",
        "users": [],
        "groupType": "sharedSigningGroup",
        "groupEmail": ""
    }
]
```

}

Documentation on that call is available here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/signinggroups/signinggroups/create/

Comment: I'm not trying to create a Signing Group, I'm trying to create a Group with a Type of "sharedSigningGroup". There are two different Categories, SigningGroups and UserGroups. Documentation on that call is available here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/usergroups/groups/create/ You can see here that "sharedSigning" is an option when creating a UserGroup Group: https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=UserGroups&tags=Groups&operations=create

Comment: What is the purpose of this Group?

Comment: Members of the sharedSigningGroup have the ability to sign documents. I grant that this is the same permission granted in a Signing Group. I'm trying to understand why sharedSigningGroup is an option in UserGroups Group when it can't be used there. Why does it not send back and error code that it is not a valid option, why does it create a customGroup? This seems like a bug to me or at least a poorly documented feature.

Comment: I will agree that this appears to be poorly documented, but the `GroupType` parameter actually seems to be read-only - you can't create a group with the `everyone` or `admin` types either. That said, It sounds like you're describing a Signing Group: To create a SharedSigningGroup, you need to use the call documented in my answer.